# How to add a method to JOptionPane

Tags: java, object, arraylist, joptionpane

I would like to call methods to my `JOptionPane`
from my main class. 
Is there any specific way to do this?

```
Dictionary word1 = new Dictionary(null);
CardCatalog catalog = new CardCatalog();

final ImageIcon welcome = new ImageIcon("welcome.jpg");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"","WELCOME TO FLASH CARD",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,welcome);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the showmessage method like this

```
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, Myclass.dosomethign());
```

but make sure the return type of the method is a string because the showmessage method takes a string as a second parameter